# python nested for loop only executes once

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 csv files. I am getting the value of a cell in one csv and comparing with all in another. Below is my code:

```
f = open('test1.csv')
x = open('test2.csv')

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
csv_x = csv.reader(x)

for row in csv_f:
    a = row[1]
    b = row[2]
    for nrow in csv_x:
        if a in nrow[0] and b in nrow[1]:
           print nrow[0]
```

Now the above code only prints for the first value of a and b. Subsequently, it is not going through the 2nd for loop for other values of a and b. Any idea what's the issue?

Comment: The thing is @anand answer is even better then mine since it has to read the file only once you could use mine only when the file size is big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function

```
csv_x = csv.reader(x)
```

Returns a file object.

When you loop through it once it goes to the end.

So you can not be able to loop through it again

To overcome this problem you could use this way

```
f = open('test1.csv')


csv_f = csv.reader(f)


for row in csv_f:
    a = row[1]
    b = row[2]
    csv_x = csv.reader(open('test2.csv')) # assign here
    for nrow in csv_x:
        if a in nrow[0] and b in nrow[1]:
           print nrow[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, correct, because after the first loop, the file `x`, based on which the csv reader `csv_x` is created is at the end of the file, and there are no more lines to be read from it, so it does not iterate through it again after first loop.

For second file, (for performance), you can consider using simple files and then creating a list before starting any loop, so that you do not have to read the same file again and again.

Example -

```
f = open('test1.csv')
x = open('test2.csv')

csv_x = csv.reader(x)
xlist = [i for i in csv_x] #If your csv is delimited by ',' , which I am guessing it is. 

csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    a = row[1]
    b = row[2]
    for nrow in xlist:
        if a in nrow[0] and b in nrow[1]:
           print nrow[0]
```