# Python - Search strings in one CSV file with nested for-loop

Tags: python, string, csv, search, nested-loops

I'm new to stackoverflow and learning with python.

I'm having some troubles with searching if several strings (taken from an input file) are in one CSV file using Python.

Basically, my python code takes strings one after the other from an input file (inputfile.csv), and searches if each string is in the first column of another file called mainfile.csv. It only compares with the first column of the mainfile.csv, which contains the relevant data I'm looking for.

**Note** : Files are quite big, over 1 million rows (and growing) for mainfile.csv and usually around 30,000 rows for inputfile.csv.

Here is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

mainfile = open('mainfile.csv', 'rb')
inputfile = open('inputfile.csv', 'rb')

mfreader = csv.reader(mainfile, delimiter=',') # mainfile reader
ifreader = csv.reader(inputfile) # inputfile reader, just one column, no delimeter

for ifrow in ifreader:
    for mfrow in mfreader:
        if ifrow[0] == mfrow[0]:
            print ifrow[0], mfrow[0] # This line is a print for debugging purpose
            print "Found a match for : %s " % ifrow[0]
            perform_some_operations()
        else:
            print ifrow[0], mfrow[0] # This line is a print for debugging purpose
            continue

mainfile.close()
inputfile.close()
```

**Problem** : 
The "nested for-loop" only steps in first row of inpufile. It "ignores" the other rows of the inputfile.csv.

> **EDIT**
>
> In fact my comprehension of the problem was wrong. The first for-loop **do
>   steps** through all the rows of the inputfile. This is the second nested for-loop which only goes once through the iteration process. And since it reaches the end, it doesn't perform any more iteration when the first for-loop iterates.

### Example files

Below are some example files. For the purpose of the example the "rows values" are simplified.

Basically, we deal with 2 files :

- MainFile : contains a list of product informations (SerialNumber, ModelNumber, Text Infos)
- InputFile : contains a list of SerialNumbers that I'm trying to find in the MainFile

**MainFile** (mainfile.csv, file size : > 1,000,000 (1M) rows)

Types : SerialNumber[varchar(64)], ModelNumber[(varchar(64)], Informations[varchar(2048)]

```
SerialNumber, ModelNumber, Informations
SN111aaa, MN123425, Informations for SN111aaa
SN222bbb, MN123425, Informations for SN222bbb
SN333ccc, MN456789, Informations for SN333ccc
SN444ddd, MN654321, Informations for SN444ddd
SN555eee, MN123425, Informations for SN555eee
```

**InputFile** (inputfile.csv, file size : ~30,000 (30K) rows)

Types : SerialNumber[varchar(64)]

```
SN000xyz
SN111xyz
SN222xyz
SN333xyz
SN444ddd
```

In the above example, since SN444ddd is the only string that can be found in both inputfile and mainfile, my python code should return me (if we dismiss the debugging lines):

```
Found a match for SN444ddd
```

And then I could perform some operations.

But it does not. What I get from the debugging print lines is :

```
$ ./myprogram.py
SN000xyz SerialNumber
SN000xyz SN111aaa
SN000xyz SN222bbb
SN000xyz SN333ccc
SN000xyz SN444ddd
SN000xyz SN555eee
$
```

Only the first row of the inputfile is processed.

> **EDIT** WRONG. cf. previous edit.

It also performs comparison with the mainfile.csv header, but that "issue" is not reallly important.

Where did I get it wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Definitely not something for CSV.  This is a job for pandas o ideally a database

Comment: Get rid of the "continue". Include a "break" in the first "if" branch.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak even if you do that we are looking at 30 million iterations here.

Comment: I agree with @e4c5, but right now I don't have the knowledge for implementing pandas or database. That will be the next step (db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that `ifreader` and `mfreader` are [*iterators*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterator#iterator-types), which means once they have exhausted the list of available items, they will not start over.

A secondary problem is that your approach is rather inefficient. Instead of going through an iterator again and again in the inner loop, I recommend making a [*set*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html?highlight=set#module-sets) of serial numbers from `inputfile.csv`. Sets cannot contain duplicate values and they are very efficient to check for the existence of a value.

So your code could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

def perform_some_operations():
    # ...
    pass

with open('inputfile.csv', 'rb') as inputfile:
    ifreader = csv.reader(inputfile) # inputfile reader, just one column, no delimeter
    serial_numbers = {row[0] for row in ifreader}

with open('mainfile.csv', 'rb') as mainfile:
    mfreader = csv.reader(mainfile, delimiter=',') # mainfile reader

    for row in mfreader:
        if row[0] in serial_numbers:
            print "match for    : %s " % row[0]
            perform_some_operations()
        else:
            print "NO MATCH for : %s " % row[0]
```

Here I have used a *set comprehension* (the curly braces) to fill the set with values from `ifreader`. After that it's easy to check the set for specific values with the `in` operator.

---

Note - instead of using `'rb'` mode to read your files, you really should use the `codings` module and specify the file encoding when opening the file.

```
import codecs

with codecs.open('inputfile.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as inputfile:
    ...
```

Use the proper `encoding` argument that matches your source data. In Python 3 the `open()` function supports the `encoding` argument natively, in Python 2 the module is there to help.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just found a similar problem answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336443/python-nested-for-loop-only-executes-once

Comment: @XavierR. No, that answer is not similar at all. It recommends something you should not do - opening and iterating the second CSV file in *every loop iteration* of the outer loop. That's a bad approach, don't do that.

Comment: Tomalak, your solution is perfect, thanks. Regarding my first comment, I meant a similar answer to my issue. The proposed solution as you rightly stated is very inefficient, although it explains how the nested for-loop effectively works with csv files. Anyway, thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Tomalak I have another question if you don't mind. When I try to start a comment with @yourname to specify who I'm replying to, the [at]yourname disappears when I click the Add Comment button. Any idea why this happen?

Comment: Yes, that's because I will get notified *anyway* when you comment on any of my posts - there is no need to @-mention me explicitly.